# TCP Networking and Desktop Applications

Tags: qt, sockets, networking, tcp, sfml

I made a two players "paint", it's like black screen and you draw with only one color, thats it. Your friend does the same. I've used Qt C++ for GUI and SFML for the drawing part. And for networking, I'm really new at this, I followed SFML guides about TCP socketing thing and its working really fine at the moment. Only problem is, I must open a port to be server, so my friend can connect me with my ip and with the port I've opened. It's ok when I use it but if I want to share this program with everyone, some people will have bad time when they can't open port.

Is there any other way to connect without opening port to be server, OR Is there  any port that every computer already allows you to use it. We tried port 80 but it doesn't seem like working.

Comment: You want to look into [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) and [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) but even if you were not new at networking that's a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- Open different ports for different clients.
- Serve them on the same port in different threads.
- Serve them on the same port in different processes.
- Serve them on the same port in an async manner.

Comment: Ah, you didn't really understand me, this program will be only 2 players, not more. One guy becomes server and his friend becomes client and thats it. Server side enters a port to listen, client side enters server's ip and also the port that server is listening. I opened port 53000 for example, and I can be the server without having any problem but some people don't know how to open ports, can't I set the port to some number that works on every computer?

Comment: @daktari: your question does not make sense to me. Try to rephrase. Every port works on every computer without firewall and similar rules.

Comment: My program can't connect if I don't use 53000, because only manually opened port in my modem is 53000.

Comment: You go to 192.168.0.1 then in your modem -> Port Forwarding -> 53000 TCP , I enter my local IP like 192.168.0.13, and after that you also add same port to Firewall in Windows, then port 53000 works.